# Null reference exception when publishing an app

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, publish

I have an application AppFoo that utilizes user controls from MyDLL.dll file.  When I run AppFoo from Visual Studio, everything works fine.  If I copy AppFoo.exe and MyDLL.dll from the debug folder created by Visual Studio and paste them to some other location (i.e. my desktop) I can launch AppFoo.exe with no issues.  However, if I use Visual Studios publish utility and publish AppFoo to some location (my Desktop again), I cannot use AppFoo.  The .exe will properly launch, but when I try to do stuff with the app, it crashes and gives me a null reference exception message.

It is quite odd to me that the error only occurs when trying to run the 'published' application, which leads me to believe that there is something going on with the publish process that is the source of my error.

Note that the user controls load fine, so there does not seem to be an issue with access to MyDLL.dll.

If you know what might be causing this, or have any troubleshooting ideas, they are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the application loads, you can attached the debugger to its process. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx). This will allow you to see where the exception is happening the same way you would if running the program from VS.

These kinds of errors are also why you want to have some kind of exception logger in your program.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for the hint.  I have tried invoking the JIT debugger, but this is a technique I was unfamiliar with.  Perhaps I am doing it wrong, but I followed the directions in the link you provided.  I attach to the process in VS2013, but when the exception is thrown in AppFoo(), VS does not do anything.  AppFoo() just crashes and gives me the error report.  Any further suggestions on this front?

Comment: @user3565566 make sure you have VS set to break on Exceptions. If this is turning out to be more trouble than it's worth, add a top level Exception handler and log the exception to a file (using its `ToString()`). That will give you a useful stack trace.

Comment: Also, make sure you've built your app in Debug (not Release) mode, and try putting the .pdb files in the same folder where you're executing.

Comment: I did publish in Debug mode, and adding the .pdb files to the folder I'm executing from.  This did not cause VS to catch the exception.  As a side note, does it matter that I'm using the 2013 Express?  I believe this is why I was unable to use JIT before.  I will add the top level exception handler and see if that gives me any useful information.

Comment: Not sure - haven't used Express before.